# WPF OnMouse Up from Template

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay so I have modified the tab control template to add two buttons, one which opens and one which saves along with the other tabs.

What I need to do is have the button run OpenSave/CloseSave function which is inside of the window. Each window will have their own open and save function as they will be different which is why I need it to use the function from within the Window.

```
<Style x:Key="EditorTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Row="2" Panel.ZIndex="1" Background="#fafafa" Padding="10" BorderBrush="#ededed" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Content="Open" Style="{StaticResource EditorButtonStyle}"/>
                            <Button Content="Save" Style="{StaticResource EditorButtonStyle}"/>
                            <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#696969" Background="#FFF">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So how would I be able to make the control template run a function which is in the Window it is used in?

Comment: So how would I be able to make the control template run a function which is in the Window it is used in?

Comment: Did binding to a `ICommand` not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Commands and Bindings. You can set the Save and Close commands in the Main Window, and then using RelativeSource for the making the bindng. You can have a window like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand Open { get; set; }    //Need to implement, maybe could be a RelayCommand or DelegateCommand, you may search in the internet
    public ICommand Save { get; set; }
}
```

And in the xaml code:

```
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Content="Open" Style="{StaticResource EditorButtonStyle}" Command="{Open, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                        <Button Content="Save" Style="{StaticResource EditorButtonStyle}" Command="{Save, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                        <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Hope this could helps...